# Can I make a new activity that has the fcm messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications and I was wondering if you can post the notification in a new activity.

for example:

I'll send a cloud message from firebase console to a device, the notification will be seen from the top panel the drag down panel and when I open the app, there's a button that will open a new activity which will contain the cloud message received by the device.

If yes, how to execute it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could trigger the function for example when a Document is Written etc... be more specific pls!

Comment: I'll edit my question. I apologize for the vague question.